# Sorting a file based on different fields and different order in Shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have a File Comprising the Below Data having "." as my Delimeter-

```
20170901.mol.settle.300001.dat

20171202.gp.charge.200002.dat

20171203.gp.charge.200003.dat

20171203.gp.charge.300003.dat

20171204.gp.depo.300004.dat

20171204.gp.fes.300009.dat

20171206.gp.depo.300010.dat

20171206.gp.fes.300006.dat
```

I was trying to Sort the Contents based on the Following Order -

1. Column 2 ASC
2. Column 1 ASC
3. Column 3 DESC
4. Column 4 ASC

Expected Output-

Tried with the Below Command and getting the output as Below-

> **sort -t "." -k2 -k1 -k3,1nr -k4 < file.txt**

```
20171202.gp.charge.200002.dat

20171203.gp.charge.200003.dat

20171203.gp.charge.300003.dat

20171204.gp.depo.300004.dat

20171206.gp.depo.300010.dat

20171206.gp.fes.300006.dat

20171204.gp.fes.300009.dat

20170901.mol.settle.300001.dat


**But this is not as per the expectation. Expected Output as Below -**


20171202.gp.charge.200002.dat

20171203.gp.charge.200003.dat

20171203.gp.charge.300003.dat

20171204.gp.fes.300009.dat

20171204.gp.depo.300004.dat

20171206.gp.fes.300006.dat

20171206.gp.depo.300010.dat

20170901.mol.settle.300001.dat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per you required output, you need to apply numeric sort for 4th column, not 3rd

```
$ sort -t. -k2,2 -k1,1 -k3,3r -k4,4n file.txt
20171202.gp.charge.200002.dat
20171203.gp.charge.200003.dat
20171203.gp.charge.300003.dat
20171204.gp.fes.300009.dat
20171204.gp.depo.300004.dat
20171206.gp.fes.300006.dat
20171206.gp.depo.300010.dat
20170901.mol.settle.300001.dat
```